# Get the user input for factory class in C++

Tags: c++, object, design-patterns, user-input, factory-pattern

In factory design,  when I create the new object with factory class I ask the user to his/her input and get the input from the user in factory class after that I create the object with these inputs.

Is it practicable to get the user input in factory class?
How should I get user input in factory class?

The factory class is below;

```
   Type *Factory::create_type(int Type){

switch(Type){

    case 1:{
        return new A(this->getUserTime(),this->getUserValue());
    }
    case 2:{
        float min = this->getUserMin();
        float max = this->getUserMax();

        if(this->validMinMax(min,max))
            return new B(this->getUserSpeed(),this >getUserValue(),min,max);
        else 
            return NULL;
    }
    case 3:{
        float min = this->getUserMin();
        float max = this->getUserMax();

        if(this->validUserMinMax(max,min))
            return new C(this->getUserSpeed(),this->getUserValue(),max,min);
        else 
            return NULL;
    }
    case 4:{
        return new D(this->getUserDistance(),this->getUserSpeed(),this->getUserValue());
    }
}}
```

One of inputs function in factory class;

```
float Factory::getUserValue(){
float m;
std::cout<<"\n enter value:";
std::cin>>m
return m; }
```

Comment: I would recommend you try to come up with an implementation that doesn't require the use of [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Enumerations is one way. Inheritance another. Templates and specializations is a third.

Comment: First of all, get outta here with that naked pointer. use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. As for the input, really you have just got 4 different methods in a switch. I would extract those to seperate methods and, if need be, make another factory or method that uses an enumeration to decide which method to call. My preferred solution would be to use another factory/class as you'd seperate the 'what-to-make' from the 'how-to-make'.

Comment: @OscardeLeeuw Sole problem with these smart pointers: You impose usage of a specific one to the user - but he/she actually might need exactly the other one... Sure, he/she can take it out and assign it to the other type, but in this specific case, I as a user would prefer just to be able to assign the bare pointer directly to the smart pointer I need to use (myself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, don't get the user input in a factory class.

Long answer: Without more context (the project size for example would be interesting) it is difficult to give an advice for a part of a single class. But nevertheless consider the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), one of the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles.

It tells us to give *one* module / class / function exactly *one* responsibility. So if you have a class that is a factory (one responsibility) and reads input from the user (second responsibility), that principle is violated.

Instead you should think of something similar to this

```
Type *Factory::create_type(int Type, const UserInput &input)
{
    switch (Type)
    {
        case 1:
            return new A(input.getTime(), input.getValue());
        case 2:
            float min = input.getMin();
            float max = input.getMax();

            /* and so on */

    }
}
```

And some

```
class UserInput
{
    public:
        Time getTime() const;
        float getMin() const;
        float getMax() const;

        /* and so on */
};
```

Alternatively the factory could have `UserInput` as a constructor parameter so it is called like this

```
UserInput input;
// read input

auto Instance = Factory(input).create_type(3);
```

Doing this you follow another important principle, the [Separation Of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

But, again, I cannot tell you what is best in your situation because I don't know the whole situation. You will find out ;-)

Comment: @Burak: Small addition: Why this principle? For better reusability! Example: Imagine some day you need your factory get the input from a file. You'd have to re-write the factory then, but could not use it any more in the old application (if you need to recompile it), so in the end, you'd have to maintain two versions... @Tobi: That's why I'd rather select another, more general name instead of `UserInput` (simply `Parameters`? -- assuming an inner class now...).

Comment: @Aconcagua In fact before I'd name a class `Parameters` or `UserInput` I'd try to find an even better name that describes and summarizes how time, value, min, and max belong together. But in this example I just couldn't make up a better name.

Comment: actually having the same problem... 'Parameters' does not describe these relations any better, you are right, but at least it is more neutral, as the input does not necessarily need to come from the user (file, windows registry, ...).

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, if required, Your factory could take an input parameter to determine which instance to create. For example, for a simple Shape factory that creates different shapes, you could take a string/ Enum that determines which shape to create. But I would strongly suggest that your factory returns Unique Ptr by value to those instances, which is called a sink so that the memory is now managed and owned by the requestor.

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual ~Shape() {}
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual void draw() override { // Implementation }
};

class Square : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual void draw() override { // Implementation }
};


class ShapeFactory
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Shape> createShape(const std::string& shapeType)
    {
        if(shapeType == "Circle")
            return std::make_unique<Circle>();
        else if(shapeType == "Square")
            return std::make_unique<Square>();
        else
            return nullptr;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please don't use a string as a parameter for choosing options. Not only is it possible to create nullptr's, but every time you call the method you'd have to remember what the exact keywords are. It is very simple to write 'Circel' by accident or 'circle' because you or another programmer forgot whether it started with a capital letter or not. Use an enum, even though you'd have to add another entry to the enum everytime you add a shape it is worth the correctness and ease-of-use.

Comment: @OscardeLeeuw Maybe we have a educational game for kids and the `std::string` parameter is the best option. But still it's dangerous to return a `nullptr`. I suggest to throw an exception instead.